# Removing a tree on a USB device in Python

Tags: python, linux, usb, usb-drive, shutil

I've used the following code to remove a tree on a USB device however I'm receiving an OSError:

I also ran the code with sudo python.

> import shutil
>
> import os
>
> src = "/media/device/my_folder"
>
> if os.path.exists(dst):
>
> ```
> shutil.rmtree(dst)
> ```

I've just used shutil.copytree(src, dst) in another script to write the files to the device in the first place. However the USB device was removed during the copy, this is probably causing the issue I'm having as all other files except the one that was half copied have been removed okay.

I'm getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "writetousb/tests/deleteTest.py", line 32, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/media/device/21823/21916.jpg'
```

So I'm guessing I'll need to change the permissions of the folder and it's files before I remove them?

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions for delete. Show full traceback.

Comment: @Denis Let me get the traceback for you now.

Comment: Hmm. Readonly filesystem usually means that the drive is mounted with the 'ro' flag, or it has been mounted with write permissions only for a specific user. You should check that you can write files to the drive using touch while logged in with the user that ran the python script.

Comment: Okay another updated. After using touch on the file I re-ran the script and it worked fine! I'll probably just loop through the folder and touch all the files using call from subprocess (unless there is a better way to call touch from python). Then run shutil.rmtree.

Comment: Okay I have a solution but I cannot post it for another 8 hours due to my reputation. I'll post it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use chmod to set the permissions correctly before I try to use shutil.rmtree then it should work. I'm going to test this and provide an update when I know it works.

I can confirm the solution works.

```
import shutil
import os

src = "/media/device/my_folder"

if os.path.exists(dst):
    os.chmod(dst, 0o777)
    for root,dirs,_ in os.walk(dst):
        for d in dirs :
            os.chmod(os.path.join(root,d) , 0o777)
    shutil.rmtree(dst)
```